# CSS media queries issue

Tags: css, media-queries

Hey everyone i'm currently struggling with media queries in my website. I need to build a website that changes certain things according to screen size of the device.

I have copied the media query from the internet and added the Meta view-port. My friend has the exact same thing and there it works fine. I've added some code as reference. This should just work right?

Could someone tell me why it doesn't?

```
/*Mobile media query*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .blue_box2{
      display:none;
  }
}
```

My HTML viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What is not working? Note that the viewport has to be below `360px` for you to see this change. My _Google Chrome_ instance only lets me shrink the viewport down to `418px` so it is possible you may not be able to see this change take effect on a desktop browser...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you got any conflicting code outside of this media query (or any inline styles in your HTML) that could cause it to function incorrectly?

The query you've shown works fine, which leads me to believe it's a problem with the code you haven't shown.

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue_box2" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blue_box2 { background:red; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .blue_box2 {
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

Just a thought:
Are you testing this using Google Chromes Developer Tools (F12), as just shrinking your browser window down normally may not reach as low as 360px.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.blue_box2{
  display:none !important;
```

}
}

or this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

My view port wouldn't work unless i put 1.0. Just wondering if the same is happening to you.